# Magento Product Reviews only by customer who purchased the product

Tags: magento

I searched everywhere, but could not find the solution for this. I want to not allow others except the buyers of that product to add review for that particular product, in Magento. Please can anybody help with this.

Comment: so do you want to give reviews to products by only registered customers?

Comment: That I am aware of disabling guest reviews, but I want to allow only the buyer of that product to be able to give review, dont want any other registered member to give review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initally make the option "Allow Guests to Write Reivews" to "No". Now, you can make this by taking the order collection of a particular product by `getProductOrderCollectionById()`. From that order collection we can get the list of the customers who purchased it.

In the other hand, you can get the ID of the logged-In customer. If the Order collection list contains the logged In customer ID, then you can allow them to display the review form.

Comment: Your answer sounds good, but i am not a programmer, is there anyway I can implement this. Please.

Comment: Sorry you cannot. As of my searching, only a developer can make this.